# Treat button release as keyboard interrupt tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, release, keyboardinterrupt

I am using tkinter in Python 3 to create a program and I'm stuck...
I have infinite loop that is triggered by button press:

```
def task13():
    while True:
        #do stuff

...

button13 = Button(root, width=25, text="13", command=task13)
goButton.pack(side=LEFT,anchor="n")
```

How could I terminate task13 on release of the button13? Is there a 'keyboard interrupt' code or can I modify the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to interrupt a running function. However, you can put a binding on `<ButtonRelease-1>` for the button, and in that binding you can set a flag. Then, in `task13` you can check for that flag at the top of your loop. You will also need a binding on `<ButtonPress-1>` to start the loop, since the `command` is tied to the release of the mouse button over the button widget.

This will only work if, while in the loop, you service events. If `#do stuff` blocks the event loop there's nothing you can do, except to run that code in a separate thread or process.

Comment: I was trying to actually implement this solution, but it wasn't working out for me ... (I have a `root.update_idletasks()`) in my infinite while loop, but still doesn't seem to work.  the '<ButtonRelease-1>' doesn't seem to get recognized...

Comment: Also, when I use a `Button`, the callback doesn't seem to even get called until the button has actually been released.

Comment: `update_idletasks` only updates _idle_ tasks such as repainting the screen. It does not process any user generated events.

Comment: What do you use to process user generated events?

Comment: @mgilson: `update`, but usually if you require `update` it means you are doing something wrong (such as embedding an infinite loop inside a GUI)

Answer (score 1):

Button have `"<Button-1>` and `<ButtonRelease-1>` events:

```
from tkinter import *

def press(*args):
    print('press')
    global pressed
    pressed = True
    master.after(0, loop)

def release(*args):
    print('release')
    global pressed
    pressed = False

def loop():
    if pressed:
        print('loop')
        # Infinite loop without delay is bad idea.
        master.after(250, loop)

master = Tk()
pressed = False

b = Button(master, text="OK")
b.bind("<Button-1>", press)
b.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", release)
b.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that re-registering a function to be run again is significantly different than an infinite loop...

Comment: I know, but  this is the simplest way.